# Javascript unable to read JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have used the following code to call API from a website.

```
function example(){
  // Call the callApi function to create a usable
  // object named apiObject from the API request URL.
  // Put the API request URL in the call
  callApi(
    'http://summary.ekmmetering.com/summary?meters=10068&key=MTAxMDoyMDIw&format=json&reports=15&limit=1&fields=kWh_Tot*',
    function(apiObject){
      // This just displays the object in the result div
      // you can use what ever code you would like to work
      // with the object here               
      var JSONOBJ = JSON.stringify(apiObject, null, 4)
      //document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSONOBJ;
      document.getElementById("meterVal").innerHTML = JSONOBJ.kWh_Tot_Min;
    }
  );
};
```

In the first line of document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSONOBJ, the output is as below.

```
[  
   {  
      "Start_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms":1486924437363,
      "End_Time_Stamp_UTC_ms":1486925099387,
      "End_Date":"Sun Feb 12 2017 18:44:59 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
      "Start_Date":"Sun Feb 12 2017 18:33:57 GMT+0000 (GMT)",
      "Meter":10068,
      "Protocol":"v3",
      "Count":663,
      "rejected_bad":0,
      "rejected_duplicates":0,
      "kWh_Tot_DeltaMin":0,
      "kWh_Tot_DeltaMax":0.1,
      "kWh_Tot_Min":127009.1,
      "kWh_Tot_Max":127009.8,
      "kWh_Tot_Diff":0.7
   }
]
```

However, once I use the second line of code

```
document.getElementById("meterVal").innerHTML = JSONOBJ.kWh_Tot_Min;
```

This comes out instead.

```
undefined
```

What do I need to do to get the right value, which is 127009.1?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `JSONOBJ[0].kWh_Tot_Min;` since `JSONOBJ` is an array by the `[]`?

Comment: I believe that JSONOBJ is a string not an array. It's in JSON format, like what you might send to the server. You could use JSON.parse to turn it back into an array. You might try apiObject[0].kWh_Tot_Min

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
 document.getElementById("meterVal").innerHTML = JSONOBJ[0].kWh_Tot_Min;
```

Comment: Please take some time to explain why this is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSONOBJ)[0].kWh_Tot_Min);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15187073)

Comment: Question: What do I need to do to get the right value, which is 127009.1?
Answer: JSON.parse(JSONOBJ)[0].kWh_Tot_Min contains the right value

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

**First**

`JSON.stringify` converts a JavaScript data structure to a string of JSON.

You need `JSON.parse` to go the other way.

**Second**

The data structure you are parsing is an *array* of *objects*.

You are ignoring the array and trying to treat it as an object.

You need to access the object in the array before you can access a property of the object.

---

```
var json = apiObject;
var myArray = JSON.parse(json);
var myObject = myArray[0];
var kWh_Tot_Min = myObject.kWh_Tot_Min;
document.getElementById("meterVal").innerHTML = kWh_Tot_Min;
```

(This can, obviously, be done without the interstitial variables, but I've broken it down for clarity).

Comment: Isn't `apiObject` already an object? Do you need to parse that?

Comment: @theKidOfArcrania — Since we can't see the code for the `callApi` function, we have no way of knowing. Since the OP is trying to use a JSON.* function, I'm assuming it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found the problem. The square brackets in the beginning and the end of the JSON string was causing the problem. After removing it with .replace(/[[]']+/g,''), the problem is solves.

Of course I have to parse the JSON string with

```
JSON.parse(JSONOBJ);
```

Thanks a lot for your help.